# Get Trimmed List Of Documents From Document Library (Professional Edition)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

So I'm building a module where I have to add commenting ability to the built-in Document library feature. I'm trying to find where I pull the documents from. I also want the list security-trimmed. I'm really hoping there's an API and I don't have to build a manual solution that breaks on an update of the document library...

Any help on where to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the DNN File Picker control, or re-purpose some of it's logic.

The source code available on Codeplex has examples of retrieving folders for a user and an example of retrieving files for a folder (for a user):

http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/58672#612642

```
Private Sub LoadFolders()
    cboFolders.Items.Clear()

    'Add Personal Folder
    If UsePersonalFolder Then
        Dim userFolder As String = FileSystemUtils.GetUserFolderPath(UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().UserID)
        Dim userFolderItem As ListItem = cboFolders.Items.FindByValue(userFolder)
        If userFolderItem IsNot Nothing Then
            userFolderItem.Text = Utilities.GetLocalizedString("MyFolder")
        Else
            'Add Dummy Folder
            cboFolders.Items.Add(New ListItem(Utilities.GetLocalizedString("MyFolder"), userFolder))
        End If
    Else
        Dim folders As ArrayList = FileSystemUtils.GetFoldersByUser(PortalId, ShowSecure, ShowDatabase, Permissions)
        For Each folder As FolderInfo In folders
            Dim folderItem As New ListItem
            If folder.FolderPath = Null.NullString Then
                folderItem.Text = Utilities.GetLocalizedString("PortalRoot")
            Else
                folderItem.Text = folder.DisplayPath
            End If
            folderItem.Value = folder.FolderPath
            cboFolders.Items.Add(folderItem)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Function GetFileList(ByVal NoneSpecified As Boolean, ByVal Folder As String) As ArrayList
    Dim fileList As ArrayList

    If IsHost Then
        fileList = Globals.GetFileList(Null.NullInteger, FileFilter, NoneSpecified, cboFolders.SelectedItem.Value)
    Else
        fileList = Globals.GetFileList(PortalId, FileFilter, NoneSpecified, cboFolders.SelectedItem.Value)
    End If

    Return fileList
End Function
```

Comment: Would pulling the files that way display the same files from the Document Library module, or would you be able to see files stored outside that module?